# Maven Build different to Dependency Tree

Tags: java, maven

I am using Maven 3 to build a java application with 3 tiers - server, ejb and ui.
The EJB project is dependent on the Server project, and the UI project is only dependent on EJB, and provides an exclusion for the Server transitive dependency.

When the UI project is built as a war, the Server dependency is being included despite it not showing up on dependency:tree command.

Here is the relevant output of running `mvn dependency:tree`

```
**project.name:UI:war:1.0 SNAPSHOT**
+-  project.name:Common:jar:1.0 SNAPSHOT:compile
|   +  org_common:_lib:jar:16.0.006:compile
|   |  +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.16:compile
|   |  \- commons configuration:commons configuration:jar:1.6:compile
|   |     +- commons lang:commons lang:jar:2.4:compile
|   |     +- commons digester:commons digester:jar:1.8:compile
|   |     \- commons beanutils:commons beanutils core:jar:1.8.0:compile
|   +- org_common:_security_lib:jar:16.0.006:compile
|   \- org.springframework:spring:jar:2.0:compile
+-  **project.name:EJB:ejb client:client:1.0 SNAPSHOT:compile**
|   \- com.ibm.websphere.appserver:j2ee:jar:7.0.0.9:compile
+-  org_common:_uicomponent:jar:16.0.006:compile
```

And here is the output dependency tree from when running `mvn clean install -X`

```
**project.name:UI:war:1.0 SNAPSHOT**
+-  project.name:Common:jar:1.0 SNAPSHOT:compile
|   +  org_common:_lib:jar:16.0.006:compile
|   |  +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.16:compile
|   |  \- commons configuration:commons configuration:jar:1.6:compile
|   |     +- commons lang:commons lang:jar:2.4:compile
|   |     +- commons digester:commons digester:jar:1.8:compile
|   |     \- commons beanutils:commons beanutils core:jar:1.8.0:compile
|   +- org_common:_security_lib:jar:16.0.006:compile
|   \- org.springframework:spring:jar:2.0:compile
+-  **project.name:EJB:ejb client:client:1.0 SNAPSHOT:compile**
|   +- **project.name:Server:jar:1.0 SNAPSHOT:compile**
|   |   +- javassist:javassist:jar:3.4.GA:compile
|   |   +- project.filestore:filestore_client:jar:7.0.003:compile
|   |   +- com.ibm.db2:db2jcc:jar:9.7.fp1.aix64.s091114:compile
|   |   +- com.ibm.db2:db2java:jar:9.7.fp1.aix64.s091114:compile
|   |   +- com.ibm.db2:db2jcc_license_cu:jar:9.7.fp1.aix64.s091114:compile
|   \- com.ibm.websphere.appserver:j2ee:jar:7.0.0.9:compile
+-  org_common:_uicomponent:jar:16.0.006:compile
```

The dependency on Server is the only difference between the two trees.
Shouldn't these two outputs always be the same? What could cause a library to be included that does not show up in dependency:tree?

The parent POM defines the modules as:

```
<modules>
    <module>Server</module>
    <module>EJB</module>
    <module>UI</module>
</modules>
```

The dependency listed in the EJB POM is:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>project.name</groupId>
            <artifactId>Server</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

The dependency in the UI is:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>project.name</groupId>
            <artifactId>EJB</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>ejb-client</type>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>project.name</groupId>
                    <artifactId>Server</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I am aware that I can explicitly exclude the Server jar from being included in the WAR, but I would prefer to fix the actual issue.

Comment: If UI depends on EJB and EJB depends on Server, then UI depends on Server. So you either exclude EJB with its transitive dependencies from `WEB-INF/lib` by setting its scope to `provided`, or you package all of them into war. To my knowledge, there is no way to include only base artifact without its transitive dependencies into war.

Comment: Are you using the most up-to-date dependency plugin (2.4) ?

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov That's why I have the exclusion on Server when the EJB project is added as a dependency to UI. The EJB tier is special in maven - it is broken into Client and Server jars - the Client jar that UI depends on does not have a dependency on Server. If the transitive dependency is excluded explicitly, why would it be included?

Comment: @khmarbaise I was not, but after updating to 2.4 the issue is the same.

Comment: Which exact Maven version do you use? If not 3.0.4, try it and tell if it helps. I've found really, REALLY crappy issues while using previous Maven 3 releases, mostly with 3.0.2.

Comment: I'm not sure that Maven understands this line `<type>ejb-client</type>`. Can I see your EJB pom.xml?

Comment: @MichalMichalski I was using maven 3.0.3, and the issue was resolved with 3.0.4. If you make your comment an answer, I'll assign the bounty to you.

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov Maven does understand it - it is a way to split an EJB tier into a jar of Client classes (remote interfaces only) and Server classes (Bean implementation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we figured out in comments, the problem's source was buggy Maven 3.0.3. Version 3.0.4 has solved the issue.

My comment there:

> Which exact Maven version do you use? If not 3.0.4, try it and tell if it helps. I've found really, REALLY crappy issues while using previous Maven 3 releases, mostly with 3.0.2.

Answer (score 5):

You are right that the output should be same in both the cases. However Maven 3 moved to using Aether for dependency resolution but as of now dependency:tree uses the old mechanism of dependency resolution which is why the difference. Check out the following link for details.

https://cwiki.apache.org/MAVEN/maven-3x-compatibility-notes.html#Maven3.xCompatibilityNotes-DependencyResolution

Because of this reason you should only rely on the output of mvn clean install -X for dependency management.

**Edit**

Since version 2.5 of the Maven Dependency Plugin, `dependency:tree` also uses Aether (see the [bug report](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MDEP-339), and the [release notes](http://jira.codehaus.org/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=11214&version=18077))

Comment: That explains why the two trees are different. Any idea how to correct the transitive dependency issue?