# Transitive Maven dependency shows up in dependency:tree but not in lib directory

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, maven-3, pom.xml

I am using Maven 3.0.3 to build a large java project. My pom.xml has a parent which depends on `spring-context` (compile scope) which in turn depends on `spring-expression` (also in the compile scope). When I create a [dependency tree](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html) with `mvn:dependencyTree` everything looks fine, the `spring-expression` library turns up as a transitive dependency in compile scope. However if I build an [effective pom](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/effective-pom-mojo.html) with `mvn help:effective-pom` the entry for `spring-expression` is missing. Also if I build the project the lib for `spring-expression` is not included in the lib directory while the one for `spring-context` is.

Until recently the library *was* included in the build, now something seems to have changed in one of the dependencies. However `spring-context` is still in the compile scope and shows up in the dependency tree, so I don't see why this should have changed the behavior.

Also, updating Maven (which seems to have solved a possibly related problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10022225/maven-build-different-to-dependency-tree)) is sadly not an option. I have temporarily fixed the problem by adding `spring-expression` as a direct rather than transitive dependency to my project but I'd rather not clog up the pom with stuff that should already be there. Any ideas?

**Update:** Weirder and weirder... While trying to come up with a minimal example I found one - sort of. This is what I came up with:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.test.project</groupId>
  <artifactId>test-project</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Test Project</name>

  <properties>
    <spring.version>3.2.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

It works in that the transitive dependency `spring-expression` is shown in the output of `mvn:dependencyTree`:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Test Project 0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:tree (default-cli) @ test-project ---
[INFO] org.test.project:test-project:war:0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:runtime
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:runtime
[INFO]    |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:runtime
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:runtime
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:runtime
[INFO]    |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:runtime
[INFO]    \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:runtime
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.922s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Apr 10 16:17:42 CEST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and not in the effective pom:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.test.project</groupId>
  <artifactId>test-project</artifactId>
  <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>Test Project</name>
  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>internal_repo</id>
      <name>Repository for internal artefacts</name>
      <url>http://internal/url</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
      <id>internal_repo</id>
      <name>Repository for internal artefacts</name>
      <url>http://internal/url</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
  </distributionManagement>
  <properties>
    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
    <spring.version>3.2.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <url>http://internal/url</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>maven3</id>
      <url>http://internal/url</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <url>http://internal/url</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>maven3</id>
      <url>http://internal/url</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>c:\projects\test-project\src\main\java</sourceDirectory>
    <scriptSourceDirectory>c:\projects\test-project\src\main\scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>c:\projects\test-project\src\test\java</testSourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>c:\projects\test-project\target\classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>c:\projects\test-project\target\test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>c:\projects\test-project\src\main\resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>c:\projects\test-project\src\test\resources</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <directory>c:\projects\test-project\target</directory>
    <finalName>test-project-0.1-SNAPSHOT</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-clean</id>
            <phase>clean</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>clean</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-install</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>install</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-resources</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>resources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testResources</id>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testResources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testCompile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-war</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>war</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-site</id>
            <phase>site</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>site</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>c:\projects\test-project\target\site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>site-deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>c:\projects\test-project\target\site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>c:\projects\test-project\target\site</outputDirectory>
          <reportPlugins>
            <reportPlugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            </reportPlugin>
          </reportPlugins>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <reporting>
    <outputDirectory>c:\projects\test-project\target\site</outputDirectory>
  </reporting>
</project>
```

*However* when I build the project the lib directory *does* include `spring-expression` in this example. How can this be?

Comment: How do you generate that "lib directory"? shade plugin, application plugin or something else? The problem is not in the transitive dependency, the problem is in the process (or its configuration) that generates "lib directory".

Comment: Post your `pom.xml`(s) so people could see what's going on. Show your tree.

Comment: @OlegEstekhin I'm no Maven expert but as far as I can tell the lib directory is built by the maven-war-plugin.

Comment: @carlspring I can't post the pom (as this is a closed source project) but I'll try to come up with a minimal example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Well, closed source, or not, you need to provide something to work with. :)

Comment: @carlspring OK, I've added an example that kind of works... :-/ See the update for details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am running with maven 3.1.1 and the dependency `spring-expression`is correctly added to WEB-INF/lib. The effective pom does not contain `spring-expression`, but that is normal as the effective pom does not resolve transitive dependencies.

The effective pom is just a merged xml file with the current pom plus all it's parents merged together. The maven dependency resolution mechanism is applied only after the effective pom is built.

This is the reason why the effective pom only contains the `spring-context` dependency, because that was the only thing specified in the pom.xml. If there would be parent dependencies in a parent pom they would show up in the effective pom too.

This is my output of mvn dependency:tree:

```
INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ test-project ---
[INFO] org.test.project:test-project:war:0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:runtime
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:runtime
[INFO]    |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:runtime
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:runtime
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:runtime
[INFO]    |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:runtime
[INFO]    \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:runtime
```

and these is my WEB-INF/lib contents:

```
aopalliance-1.0.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
spring-aop-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar
```

So the issue seems to be some misunderstanding of the effective pom feature together with a missing dependency `spring-expression` in WEB-INF lib due to a maven bug: this problem is solvable via version upgrade or hardcoding dependency on the pom as workaround as you found out.

Comment: OK, it seems I did indeed misunderstand the effective pom mechanism. Thanks for explaining. I still can't find out however, why the lib is not pulled any more; something must have changed in the dependencies but I don't know why that would make it stop pulling `spring-expression`. I'll try to find more information to provide so as to find the cause...

Comment: Maybe something is messed up in your maven repository. Have you tried to delete .m2/org/springframework and do a clean run?

Comment: @Wouter Yes, I tried that. Didn't work But I can now no longer reproduce the problem... Ah well, it works. If I ever stumble upon this again, I'll try to find out what was going on then.

Comment: Might have been a caching problem. Try mvn -U if you ever run into something like this again.

Answer (score 1):

Lib `spring-expression` is not in lib directory when you build your large java project, but is in your minimal example's. And I noticed that you were using maven 3.0.3, this problem is caused by this bug [MNG-5121](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5121).